# Reasons for absence of performance test for oss database systems?

Tags: database, jdbc, open-source, benchmarking, performance-testing

I used open source java implementation of TPC-C benchmark (called TCJ - TPC-C via JDBC (created by MMatejka last year)) to compare the performance of Oracle and 2 OSS DBMS.

TPC-C is standard in the proprietary sphere and my question is:

What are the main reasons that there is not systematically implemented performance test for OSS database systems?

Comment: Nobody is pushing it, there is no funding to push it, all platforms are different slightly whereas TPC suite mandates very tight requirements (alternative solutions can beat TPC, but arent allowed as they bend the rules) Don't get me wrong, I wish there was a more level playing field.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand...

you mean that there is no money and somebody who would realize it?

every database system is slightly different, am I right? So, why is it so specific for OSS?

What do u mean alternative sol can beat TPC? (what alternative sol? what rules?)

I am new here so I apologise for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @StevePatris For OSS there is probably no perceived value for spending a lot of time getting a benchmark to work, time that can be better spent on fixing bugs or writing new features. While for commercial vendors it can be an additional 'sales' argument.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not sure your question is a perfect fit for SO as it is getting close to asking opinion, and so all of my answer is more opinion than fact. most of this I have read over the years, but will struggle to find references/proof anymore. I am not a TPC member, but did heavily investigate trying to get a dsitributed column store database tested under the TPC-H suite.

**Benchmarks**

These are great at testing a single feature and comparing them, unfortunately, that is nowhere as easy as it sounds. Companies will spend large amounts of effort to get better results, sometimes (so I have heard) implementing specific functions in the source for a benchmark.  There is a lot of discussion about how reliable benchmark results are overall. Also, a benchmark may be a perfect fit for some product, but not another.

Your example uses Jdbc, but not every database has jdbc, or worse it may be a 'minor bolt on' just to enable that class of application. So performing benchmarks via jdbc when all main usage will be embedded sql may portray some solutions unfairly/poorly.

There is some arguments around that benchmarks distract vendors from real priorities, they spend effort and implement features solely for benchmarks.

Benchmarks can also be very easily misunderstood, even TPC is a suite of different benchmarks and you need to select the correct one for your needs ( tpc-c for oltp, tpc-h for dss etc)

**TPC**

If this reads as negative for tpc, please forgive me, I am pro tpc.

Tpc defines a very tight set of test requirements. You must follow these to a letter. For tpc-h this is an example of what you must do

1. do multiple runs, some in parallel, some single user
2. use exactly the sql provided, you must not change it at all. If you need to because your system uses a slightly different syntax, but must get a waiver.
3. you must use an external auditor.
4. you may not index colmns etc beyond what is specified.
5. for tpch you must do writing in a specified way (which eliminates 'single writer' style databases)

The above ensures that people reading the results can have trust in the integrity of the results, which is great for a corporate buyer.

Tpc is a non profit org and anybody can join. There is a fee but it isnt a major barrier, except for OSS. You are only realistically going to pay this fee if you think you can achieve really great results, or you need published results to bid for govt contracts etc.

The biggest problem I see with tpc for oss is that it is heavily skewed towards relational vendors and very few oss solutions can met the entry criteria with their offerings, or if they do they may not perform well enough for every test.  Doing a benchmark may also be a distraction for some teams.

**Alternatives to tpc**

Of course alternatives exist to tpc, but none really gain traction, as yet, that i am aware of. Major vendors often stipulate that you cannot benchmark their products and publish the results. So any new benchmark will need to be politically astutue to get them on board. I agree with the vendors stance here, I would hate someone to mis-implement a benchmark and report my product poorly.

The database landscape has fractured a lot since tpc started, but many 'bet you business' applications still run on 'classic' databases, so they still have a place. However, with the rise in nosql etc, there is a place for new benchmarks, but the real question becomes what to measure - even chosing xyz like '%kitten%'.  Or xyz like 'kitten%'.  Will have dramatic effects on different solutions. If you solve that, what common interface wil,you allow (odbc, jdbc, http/ajax, embedded sql, etc) each of these interfaces affects performance greatly.  What about the actual models, such as ACID for relational models vs eventual consistency models? What about hardware/software solutions that use specificaly designed hardware?

Each database has made design trade offs for different needs, and a benchmark is attempting to level the playing field, which is only really possible if you have something in common, or report lots of different metrics.

One of the problems with trying to create an alternative is that 'who will pay'? You need consenus over the type of tests to perform, and then you need to audit results for them to be meaningful. This all costs money.